# How to provide your own JWT signing key to Firebase Auth

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

My users are logging in using custom authentication system on my website, which is returning JWT signed by my company's private key.
I'm trying to enable users to login to Firebase as described in [Authenticate with Firebase in JavaScript Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

If I understand correctly by reading the instruction I'm supposed to:

- create service account in Firebase
- download its private key
- copy the private key to my authentication server
- sign JWTs using this key

However, I need to stick to using my company's key to sign JWT.

Is it possible? If so, how can I provide my company's public key to Firebase for it to be able to decode my JWT? Or is my understanding about the flow wrong?

Comment: There is no way to specify what key Firebase should use for decoding the JWT on its servers. Why do you need to stick with your company's key?

Comment: Ah, that's too bad, thank you Frank. The only reason is we have legacy  auth system which generates JWTs that we're using for several other systems and I can't update it. I'll think about another solution then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify what key Firebase should use for decoding the JWT. The requirement also doesn't make sense, since you're interacting with Firebase's backend services. If you interact with multiple backend systems, you'll need to mint a separate token for each.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? Since JWT tokens are signed Firebase could support validating them?

Comment: If you think it's a reasonable use-case, I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report).